# Calculate similarity of symbolic matrix and power of some variable of that symbolic matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, exponentiation

I have the matrices

$ A=\left( \begin{matrix} α & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & α & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & α \end{matrix} \right)$  and  $ N=\left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$

I need to prove that $AN=NA$, and then calculate $(A+N)^k$

Do I have to use characteristic polynominal to proof it ?

For matrix N, I have calculated : $det(N) = 0$, $ Eigenvalue = 0$, $ Eigenvector = [1,0,0]$

I'm not sure how to calculate with the matrix A, I need proof this manually (not using software). And as for the power of k, how do you calculate matrix with the power of some variable when the matrix itself is symbolic  ?

Thanks !

Comment: Hint: You might want to write out what $(A+N)^3$ is in terms of $A$ and $N$, without plugging in their actual definitions; the binomial theorem is your friend.

Comment: "how do you calculate matrix with the power of some variable when the matrix itself is symbolic?" For example, if $A=(\alpha)$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix, then $A^k=(\alpha^k)$. Now take block matrices of these for your $A$. So $A^k=diag(\alpha^k,\alpha^k,\alpha^k)$.

Comment: @JohnHughes yes, edited !

Comment: Note that since the product commutes, you will be able to collect terms $\alpha AB$ and $\beta BA$ etc... Hence you can expand using the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need characteristic polynomials.

**Hint 1.** Your matrix $A$ could be written shorter as $\alpha I$, and scalar multiples of the identity matrix commute with everything!

**Hint 2.** There is a simple pattern to the powers of your $N$. Compute the first few powers by hand, and it will be *impossible* for you not to notice it.

**Hint 3.** Since $A$ and $N$ commute, the binomial theorem applies to $(A+N)^k$.

**Hint 4.** After you have combined hints 2 and 3, collect like terms. Notice that the big complex coefficient is *almost* equal to the binomial expansion of $(\alpha+1)^k$.